# Improve relationship between 3 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, database-administration

I have 3 tables on my database: `users`, `payment_methods` and `user_blocked_pm`. The `users` table speaks for itself, the `payment_methods` stores all the payment methods the company uses, and the `user_blocked_pm` has the payment methods blocked for a specific user.

```
+------------------+
|       users      |
+-----+------------+
|  id |  user_name |
+-----+------------+
|   1 |       John |
|   2 |      Davis |
+-----+------------+

+-----------------------+
|    payment_methods    |
+-----+-----------------+
|  id |  payment_method |
+-----+-----------------+
|   1 |     credit_card |
|   2 |            cash |
+-----+-----------------+

+-----------------------------------+
|          user_blocked_pm          |
+-----+---------+-------------------+
|  id | user_id | payment_method_id |
+-----+---------+-------------------+
|   1 |       1 |                 1 |
|   2 |       1 |                 2 |
|   3 |       2 |                 2 |
+-----+---------+-------------------+
```

So, following the structure above, both `payment_methods` are blocked for the user John and `cash` is blocked for Davis.

Following this structure when there are multiple users and payment methods I'll have multiple records on `user_blocked_pm` because each user will be allowed to use only a few of the payment methods.

Is there a better way to work this relationship between the `users` and the `user_blocked_pm` so that the table doesn't get gigantic?

Comment: Note that id in ubpm is redundant

Comment: So you could add a field at the user level to indicating all payment methods are blocked OR you could allow individual blocks at the user_blocked_PM.  and note the table shouldn't be huge.  I would hope most customers and payment methods aren't blocked

Comment: @xQbert, this was working fine for a small number of pm's until a user decided to create around 72 of them based on payment term, and different cities of the state making the blocked_pm table around 134k rows...

Answer (score 0):

- You do not need the **id** column in **user_blocked_pm** table because you going to select on user_id or pm_id
- If the number of the allowed pm is less then the number of the not allowed, why not to make a **user_allowed_pm** table instead of **user_blocked_pm**
- If you have a fixed number of pm for each user then you do not need a table just you create a column for every pm and you put the key of the pm (like a foreign key)

Comment: I'll remove the id column in the user_blocked_pm but here is the thing, in this particular case, the number of blocked pm is less than the allowed pm and no, unfortunately the number of pm for each user isn't fixed...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a few user "types", then perhaps you can replace the `user_blocked_pm` with a `user_type_blocked_pm`. A "type" is a set of blocked/permitted payment methods. So the `user_type_blocked_pm` table is small -- has entries for the different types (users who can pay with cash only, users who can pay with credit and cash, etc. ) Then, you can add a column to the `users` table to indicate the user type.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine, and the other ideas so far suggested are also fine. If the number of payment types is small (not more than 7, say - and certainly less than 64!), and finite, then you might also consider a bitwise method, where 1 = credit_card, 2 = cash, and 3 = both. I do this for days of the week, which are unlikely to ever be more than 7.

Comment: You obviously haven't seen my Kickstarter for lobbying funds for Strawberrday. I'm thinking it would go between Dataday and Stackerday.